# how to convert a datetime.date object to string in python

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

When trying to fetch dates from `mysql`, and doing a json.dunps on the result for sending it back to html, get this following error :

`TypeError: datetime.date(2019, 6, 26) is not JSON serializable`

My db result set looks like :

```
[[(B, datetime.date(2019, 6, 26)), (A, datetime.date(2019, 6, 26))], 
 [(A, datetime.date(2019, 6, 26)), (B, '0000-00-00')]]
```

Tried converting the `date object` to string using `strftime`. Does not work.

```py
row_headers = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
for result in rows:
    json_data.append(zip(row_headers, result))

for tup in i:
  core, last_modified = tup
  if last_modified is not None:
    last_modified = datetime.strftime(last_modified, '%d-%m-%M')
    t = datetime.datetime(last_modified)
    t.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

final_result = {'data': json_data}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(final_result), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: re-organizing the code to focus only on the specific error would help . there are few unknowns here, 1) datetime.strftime there is no such method in datetime. 2) what is value of i? 3) is rows = DB results?? else whats the value of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(final_result, default=str), content_type='application/json')
```